# Finding $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{\sin x}$

This is how I started but I get to a dead end fast:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\ln x^{\sin x}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{\sin x \ln x}$

I guess I can bound it below with $e^0=1$ but I have no idea with what from above.

Any advice on how to continue ?

PS: we can't use integration/derivation nor Taylor's theorem because we haven't covered that.

Comment: What definition of $\sin x$ are you using / allowed to use ?

Comment: @Eckhard $lim_{x\to 0} \frac{sinx}{x}=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-x \le \sin x \le x$ for small positive $x$, therefore

$x^{\sin x}\ge x^x $

and
$x^{-x} \ge x^{\sin x}$

Therefore, since
$\lim_{x \to 0} x^{x} = 1$ the result follows and $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{\sin(x)} = 1$

Comment: Very nice. But why did the inequalities flip when they went to the exponent ?

Comment: @GinKin the function $x^x$ is decreasing in $(0,e^{-1})$.

Comment: @egreg Ohhh that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** Note that 
$$(\sin x)(\ln x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}(x\ln x).$$

Comment: Very good hint indeed. +1

Comment: So we're left with showing that $xlnx$ goes to zero. Is there another way to do it other than L'hopital? because as I said above, we can't derive.

Comment: If you cannot differentiate at all, then there is trouble. It depends on the exact way $\ln x$ (or the exponential) are defined. But for example we can let $x=e^{-t}$. Then $x\ln x=-\frac{t}{e^t}$. We want to show this approaches $0$ as $t\to\infty$. By the Binomial Theorem, if $t$ is an **integer** greater than $1$, then $e^t=(1+(e-1))^t \ge 1+(e-1)t+\frac{(e-1)^2}{2}t^2$. Divide $t$ by this. The result clearly approaches $0$.

Comment: The issue is that the usual formal definitions of $e^x$ and $\ln x$, and verification of their basic properties, are calculus-dependent. In the above "no calculus" way, I have assumed implicitly that $e^u$ is an increasing function, so that I can use Binomial Theorem, which tells me about the size of $1+(e-1))^t$ when $t$ is an integer, to get information even at non-integers.

Comment: I don't get how you can multiply the right side (the smaller side) with t and $t^2$.

Comment: In the inequality, previous comment, can use instead $e^t\gt ((e-1)^2/2)t^2$. Then $t/e^t \le \frac{2}{(e-1)^2 t}$, and this goes to $0$ as the integer $t\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin x\sim_0 x$ the needed result follows easily if we show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}x\ln x=0$:

$$\lim_{x\to0}x\ln x=_{x=\frac{1}{y}}-\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{\ln y}{y}=_{HR}-\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{1}{y}=0$$

Comment: HR ? also, how come in the ln it isn't 1/y ?

Comment: HR=Hospital rule.

Comment: Well, we can't use derivation as I said above, is there another way to show that it goes to zero without HR ? And why it isn't $\lim_{y\to+\infty}\frac{\ln \frac1y}{y}$ ?